# Mount-SPContentDatabase No Root-Web

Tags: database, sharepoint-2010, sitecollection

I want to Mount an existing ContentDatabase with the following command:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase Content_WSS_Name -WebApplication http://name -AssignNewDatabaseId
```

It runs without an error but says that the site count is 0. I can see the database under Manage Content Databases in Central Admin but the site count is also 0  and no site collection shows up under site collections section.

EDIT:
New Database, because i have the same Database connected to another SiteColletion, and want a Copy of this.

Comment: mount-spcontentdatabase is for attaching existing content dbs to a farm...  What do you mean by "new ContentDatabase"?

Comment: New Database, because i have the same Database connected to another SiteColletion, and want a Copy of this.

Comment: have your read this article?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328.aspx

Comment: SharePoint related questions would be very welcome on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) - you might want to consider posting it there, or better still asking for it to be migrated.

Comment: Did  you get your problem resolved  ? I am also getting the same problem.

Comment: No Sorry. A take a different way and restored the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Try stsadm.exe o addcontentdatabase .............make sure the database has site collection you can use recover from un attached database option on CA. Another thing to check is that web app you are trying to attach  to does not have root level site collection ,because in  case you have root level SC in database it will fail.

Let me know your outcome ?

Thanks